# First 10 long running transactions

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, ignite, apacheignite

I have a fairly small cluster of 6 nodes, 3 client, and 3 server nodes. Important configurations,

storeKeepBinary = true,

cacheMode = Partitioned (some caches's about 5-8, out of 25 have this as TRANSACTIONAL)

AtomicityMode = Atomic

backups = 1

readFromBackups = false

no persistence

When I run the app for some load/performance test on-prem on 2 large boxes, 3 clients on one box, and 3 servers on another box, all within docker containers, I get a decent performance.

However, when I move them over to AWS and run them in EKS, the only change I make is to change the cluster discovery from standard TCP (default) to Kubernetes-based discovery and run the same test.

But now the performance is very bad, I keep getting,

WARN [sys-#145%test%] - [org.apache.ignite] First 10 long-running transactions [total=3]

Here the transactions are running more than a min long.

In other cases, I am getting,
WARN [sys-#196%test-2%] - [org.apache.ignite] First 10 long-running cache futures [total=1]

Here the associated future has been running for > 3 min.

Most of the places 'google search' has taken me, talks flaky/inconsistent n/w as the cause.

The app and the test seem to be ok since on a local on-prem this works just fine and the performance is decent as well.

Wanted to check if others have faced this or when running on Kubernetes in the public cloud something else needs to be done. Like somewhere I read nodes need to be pinned to the host in a cloud/virtual environment, but it's not mandatory.

TIA